# setting a before/after hook for methods in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i set a before/after "hook" for methods in node.js?

i need it to execute certain actions before certain method is called. I'm using node.js 10.36 with socket.io 1.2.

Comment: You'lll want to look in aspect-oriented programming and function decorators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Extending `Function`:**

Here is a little extension to `Function.Prototype`

```
Function.prototype.before = function (callback) {
    var that = this;
    return (function() {
        callback.apply(this, arguments);
        return (that.apply(this, arguments));
    });
}

Function.prototype.after = function (callback) {
    var that = this;
    return (function() {
        var result = that.apply(this, arguments);
        callback.apply(this, arguments);
        return (result);
    });
}
```

These two extensions return the function to call.

**Here is a little example:**

```
function test(a) {
    console.log('In test function ! a = ', a);
}
test(15); // "In test function ! a =  15"
```

**With before:**

```
var beforeUsed = test.before(function(a) {
    console.log('Before. Parameter = ', a);
});
beforeUsed(65); // "Before. Parameter =  65"
                // "In test function ! a =  65"
```

**With after:**

```
var afterUsed = beforeUsed.after(function(a) {
    console.log('After. Parameter = ', a);
});
afterUsed(17); // "Before. Parameter =  17"
               // "In test function ! a =  17"
               // "After. Parameter =  17"
```

**You also can chain:**

```
var both = test.before(function(a) {
    console.log('Before. Parameter = ', a);
}).after(function(a) {
    console.log('After. Parameter = ', a);
});
both(17); // Prints as above
```